# How to get email type using EWS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

i'm trying to find the diference between a normal mail and a notification mail (read:, delivery notification failure:, etc)
it this possible?

My development environment is asp.net c# Exchange-server 2010 Thank you.

> ExchangeService ews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);

Comment: [How to work with Exchange EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535506%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) have you checked this documentation or others related to using `EWS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the best way is to check the Message Class via the ItemClass property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/exchangewebservices.itemtype.itemclass(v=exchg.150).aspx eg on a delivery report it should be Report.IPM.Note.DR see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842141(v=office.15).aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks! the itemclass was i lookinf for.

this types 

Value -Meaning
REPORT.IPM.NOTE.NDR
Non-delivery report for a standard message.
REPORT.IPM.NOTE.DR
Delivery receipt for a standard message.
REPORT.IPM.NOTE.DELAYED
Delivery receipt for a delayed message.